# Memoir package: remove header or footer to get more space

Tags: header-footer, memoir

How can I remove either the header or the footer of the page using `memoir`?

When I say "remove", read "take no space on the page";
I want to make the block taller by using that space.

(non)Working Example

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
% Using a5paper to see differences more easily

\makepagestyle{myplain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{A plain style}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{A plain style}{\thepage}

\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{0pt} % <-- no effect?
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myplain}
First page. Nothing special.

\vspace*{\fill}

End of the page.

\clearpage

\pagestyle{myplain}
Second page. Compare to third page 
(if your pdf viewer allows you to see pages side by side)

\vspace*{\fill}

End of the page.

\clearpage\pagestyle{plain}

Third page.

\vspace*{\fill}

End of the page.

\clearpage\pagestyle{myplain}

Fourth page.

\vspace*{\fill}

End of the page.
\end{document}
```

In the example above, the text blocks on both pagestyles have the same size.

Perhaps this is related to the answer: 
if my document has no footer, then *no* page style
can have one. But in that case… 
would I have to remove the default page styles?

**Edit:** Here is how I circumvented the problem. I still get a warning, but the effect is what I wanted.

```
\documentclass[10pt,extrafontsizes,landscape,twocolumn,article]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Size of the block of text (height, width) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% A4: 29.7 cm x 21 cm
\settypeblocksize{19cm}{23.7cm}{*} % vertical, horizontal, ratio
\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{0pt}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1} % left, right, ratio
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1} % upper, lower, ratio 

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}

\checkandfixthelayout

% Page style %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makepagestyle{myplain}

\makeevenhead{myplain}{\footnotesize \thepage}{}{\footnotesize Author}
 \makeoddhead{myplain}{\footnotesize Author}{}{\footnotesize \thepage}

\makeevenfoot{myplain}{}{}{}
 \makeoddfoot{myplain}{}{}{}

\pagestyle{myplain}

\begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
First page. Nothing special.

\vspace*{\fill}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace*{\fill}

End of the page.

\clearpage

\lipsum[4-15]
\end{document}
```

Which generates the warnings

```
Class memoir Warning: The material used in the footer is too large
(8.39996pt) for the given foot skip (0.0pt), it is recommended to
either increase the foot skip or redesign the fotoer
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 41.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2]

Class memoir Warning: The material used in the footer is too large
(8.39996pt) for the given foot skip (0.0pt), it is recommended to
either increase the foot skip or redesign the fotoer
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 44.
```

Comment: What exactly is it you are asking for?

Comment: I would like to use the space of the footer for the block of the text, so that I can have more text in a page.

Comment: Then what does have have to do with the page style? The page style is not applied to the text block. It sits out side. Just change the margins

Comment: Changing the margins yields a warning. I wonder if this is because there is no way of knowing what can be put to the footer by the pagestyle. The warning is `Class memoir Warning: The material used in the footer is too large
(8.39996pt) for the given foot skip (0.0pt), it is recommended to
either increase the foot skip or redesign the fotoer
(in both cases you will find help in the memoir manual). on input line 8.` By the way, just spotted the typo at the warning (fotoer).

Comment: @daleif, thank you for the suggestions (and for maintaining memoir!!) I have added my current approach to the question.

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that all styles (expect empty) contains a strut. As you'd probably not want the text to go straight to the bottom edge of the paper, just set the foot height to say 9pt, it will not affect the text block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32448/discussion-between-tassio-and-daleif).

Comment: @daleif or Tássio Anybody answering? :-)

Comment: It's on the todo list :) I will enter vacation in a few weeks, I can write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks you @daleif for your comment!

As @daleif explained, it suffices to set the height of the footer (`\footskip`, as in page 9 of the [memoir manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)). The only change is 
adding the line `\setlength{\footskip}{9pt}` somewhere after setting the margins, and before `\checkandfixthelayout`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,extrafontsizes,landscape,twocolumn,article]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Page setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Size of the block of text (height, width) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% A4: 29.7 cm x 21 cm
\settypeblocksize{19cm}{23.7cm}{*} % vertical, horizontal, ratio
\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{0pt}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1} % left, right, ratio
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1} % upper, lower, ratio

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{9pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

% Page style %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makepagestyle{myplain}

\makeevenhead{myplain}{\footnotesize \thepage}{}{\footnotesize Author}
\makeoddhead{myplain}{\footnotesize Author}{}{\footnotesize \thepage}

\makeevenfoot{myplain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myplain}{}{}{}

\pagestyle{myplain}

\begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
First page. Nothing special.

\vspace*{\fill}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace*{\fill}

End of the page.

\clearpage

\lipsum[4-15]
\end{document}
```