# Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry

Tags: xetex, errors, hyperref, compilation-error

I am trying to build a template with command "xelatex -shell-escape -file-line-error main-csae" and I get this error.

Main file:

```
\documentclass[14pt, oneside]{bachelor}

\title{Название дипломного проекта}

\date{\the\year}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\setcounter{page}{2}
\makeabstract

\tableofcontents

\makelastpage

\end{document}
```

Class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{altsu-bachelor}[2020/03/31 version 0.2 AltSU Template for CSaE Bachelor]
 
%% Extreport options
\DeclareOption{14pt}{
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extreport}
}

%% Execute default options
\ExecuteOptions{14pt}

%% Process given options
\ProcessOptions*

% Загрузка основного класса
\LoadClass[a4paper, oneside]{extreport}

% Загрузка дополнительных пакетов и настрока команд.
% Параметры полей для страницы.
\RequirePackage{xltxtra}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553392/latex-rule-filling-the-line
%%% Интервалы %%%
%% По ГОСТ Р 7.0.11-2011, пункту 5.3.6 требуется полуторный интервал
%% Реализация средствами класса (на основе setspace) ближе к типографской классике.
%% И правит сразу и в таблицах (если со звёздочкой)
%\DoubleSpacing*     % Двойной интервал
%\OnehalfSpacing*    % Полуторный интервал
%\setSpacing{1.42}   % Полуторный интервал, подобный Ворду (возможно, стоит включать вместе с предыдущей строкой)
\onehalfspacing

%%% Макет страницы %%%
% Выставляем значения полей (ГОСТ 7.0.11-2011, 5.3.7)
\RequirePackage[a4paper, left=3cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, nofoot, nomarginpar]{geometry} %, heightrounded, showframe
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}   %размер дополнительного верхнего поля
\setlength{\footskip}{12.3pt} % снимет warning, согласно https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334346

%%% Выравнивание и переносы %%%
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241343/what-is-the-meaning-of-fussy-sloppy-emergencystretch-tolerance-hbadness
%% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=70342#p70342
\tolerance 1414
\hbadness 1414
\emergencystretch 1.5em % В случае проблем регулировать в первую очередь
\hfuzz 0.3pt
\vfuzz \hfuzz
%\raggedbottom
%\sloppy                 % Избавляемся от переполнений
\clubpenalty=10000      % Запрещаем разрыв страницы после первой строки абзаца
\widowpenalty=10000     % Запрещаем разрыв страницы после последней строки абзаца
\brokenpenalty=4991     % Ограничение на разрыв страницы, если строка заканчивается переносом

% Математические дополнения от AMS
\RequirePackage{amsthm, amsmath, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}[2014/05/21]

\RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{float}

%%% Таблицы %%%
\RequirePackage{booktabs, longtable, ltcaption, tabulary, tabu}
% Улучшенное форматирование таблиц
\RequirePackage{multirow, makecell} 

% для вертикального центрирования ячеек в tabulary
\def\zz{\ifx\[$\else\aftergroup\zzz\fi}
%$ \] % <-- чиним подсветку синтаксиса в некоторых редакторах
\def\zzz{\setbox0\lastbox
\dimen0\dimexpr\extrarowheight + \ht0-\dp0
\setbox0\hbox{\raise-.5\dimen0\box0}%
\ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+\extrarowheight
\dp0=\dimexpr\dp0+\extrarowheight
\box0
}

% Поддержка переносоустойчивых подчёркиваний и зачёркиваний
\RequirePackage{soulutf8}
% Запятая в десятичных дробях
\RequirePackage{icomma}
% Красная строка.
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}
\RequirePackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
% Пакет отвечающий за листинги.
\RequirePackage[newfloat]{minted}
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Листинг}

%%% Счётчики %%%
% Счётчик рисунков и таблиц
\RequirePackage[figure,table]{totalcount}
% Пакет создания счётчиков на основе последнего номера подсчитываемого элемента (может требовать дважды компилировать документ)
\RequirePackage{totcount}
% Счётчик страниц, совместимый с hyperref (ссылается на номер последней страницы). Желательно ставить последним пакетом в преамбуле
\RequirePackage{totpages}

%%http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/6993203#comment-6994589 (используется totcount)
%\makeatletter
\def\formbytotal#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \newcount\@c
    \@c\totvalue{#1}
    \newcount\@last
    \newcount\@pnul
    \@last\@c
    \divide\@last 10
    \@pnul\@last
    \divide\@pnul 10
    \multiply\@pnul-10
    \advance\@pnul\@last
    \multiply\@last-10
    \advance\@last\@c
    \total{#1}~#2%
    \ifnum\@pnul=1#5\else%
    \ifcase\@last#5\or#3\or#4\or#4\or#4\else#5\fi
    \fi
}
%\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
%% регистрируем счётчики в системе totcounter
    \regtotcounter{totalcount@figure}
    \regtotcounter{totalcount@table}       % Если иным способом поставить в преамбуле то ошибка в числе таблиц
    \regtotcounter{TotPages}               % Если иным способом поставить в преамбуле то ошибка в числе страниц
    \setlength{\parindent}{12.5mm}%{2.5em}                   % Абзацный отступ. Должен быть одинаковым по всему тексту и равен пяти знакам (ГОСТ Р 7.0.11-2011, 5.3.7).
}


\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}  %% свойства шрифтов по умолчанию. Для XeTeX опцию Renderer=Basic можно не указывать, она необходима для LuaTeX
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman} %% задаёт основной шрифт документа
%\setkeys{russian}{babelshorthands=true}

\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}

\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Times New Roman} 
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontrm}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfontsf}{Arial}

\addto\captionsrussian{%
%%% Переопределение именований %%%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Содержание} % (ГОСТ Р 7.0.11-2011, 4)
  \renewcommand{\figurename}{Рис.} % (ГОСТ Р 7.0.11-2011, 5.3.9)
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Таблица} % (ГОСТ Р 7.0.11-2011, 5.3.10)
%  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Список рисунков}
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Список таблиц}
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\theenumiii}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.\arabic{enumiii}}

%%% Оглавление %%%
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]
  {\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
  {\contentslabel{1.5em}\hspace*{0em}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}%
   {\centering\normalfont\bfseries}
   {\thechapter.}
   {14pt}
   {\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{\section}%
   {\centering\normalfont\bfseries}
   {\thesection.}
   {14pt}
   {}
   
 \titleformat{\subsection} % command
    [hang]                 % shape
    {\centering\bfseries\normalsize} % format
    {\thesubsection.}       % label
    {1em}                  % Spacing between label and title
    {}                     % before code
%\titlespacing{\subsection}% Set the spacing around the title
%{0pt}                  % Left
%{0pt}                  % Above
%{0pt}                  % Below
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{*0}{15pt}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{6pt}

\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage{epigraph}
\RequirePackage{enumitem} %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6081/reduce-space-between-enumerated-items
\setlist{nolistsep}
%\renewcommand{\@listI}{%
%\leftmargin=25pt
%\rightmargin=0pt
%\labelsep=5pt
%\labelwidth=20pt
%\itemindent=0pt
%\listparindent=0pt
%\topsep=0pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
%\partopsep=0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
%\parsep=0pt plus 1pt
%\itemsep=\parsep}

\RequirePackage[
    backend=biber, 
    sorting=nyt,
    bibstyle=gost-numeric,%gost-authoryear,
    citestyle=gost-numeric%gost-authoryear
]{biblatex}
\urlstyle{same}

%% Additional TeX/LaTeX code...
% Объявление переменных
\newcommand{\@ministry}{\#}
\newcommand{\ministry}[1]{\edef\@ministry{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@country}{\#}
\newcommand{\country}[1]{\edef\@country{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@fulluniversityname}{\#}
\newcommand{\fulluniversityname}[1]{\edef\@fulluniversityname{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@institute}{\#}
\newcommand{\institute}[1]{\edef\@institute{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@department}{\#}
\newcommand{\department}[1]{\edef\@department{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@departmentchief}{\#}
\newcommand{\departmentchief}[1]{\edef\@departmentchief{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@departmentchiefdegree}{\#}
\newcommand{\departmentchiefdegree}[1]{\edef\@departmentchiefdegree{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@shortdepartment}{\#}
\newcommand{\shortdepartment}[1]{\edef\@shortdepartment{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@supervisort}{\#}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\edef\@supervisor{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@supervisordegree}{\#}
\newcommand{\supervisordegree}[1]{\edef\@supervisordegree{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommission}{\#}
\newcommand{\ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommission}[1]{\edef\@ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommission{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommissiondegree}{\#}
\newcommand{\ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommissiondegree}[1]{\edef\@ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommissiondegree{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@groupnumber}{\#}
\newcommand{\groupnumber}[1]{\edef\@groupnumber{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@keysRU}{\#}
\newcommand{\keysRU}[1]{\edef\@keysRU{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@keysEN}{\#}
\newcommand{\keysEN}[1]{\edef\@keysEN{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@UDC}{\#}
\newcommand{\UDC}[1]{\edef\@UDC{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@docname}{\#}
\newcommand{\docname}[1]{\edef\@docname{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@GradebookNumber}{\#}
\newcommand{\GradebookNumber}[1]{\edef\@GradebookNumber{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@Consultant}{\#}
\newcommand{\Consultant}[1]{\edef\@Consultant{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@Consultantdegree}{\#}
\newcommand{\Consultantdegree}[1]{\edef\@Consultantdegree{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@NormController}{\#}
\newcommand{\NormController}[1]{\edef\@NormController{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@NormControllerdegree}{\#}
\newcommand{\NormControllerdegree}[1]{\edef\@NormControllerdegree{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@abstractRU}{\#}
\newcommand{\abstractRU}[1]{\edef\@abstractRU{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@abstractEN}{\#}
\newcommand{\abstractEN}[1]{\edef\@abstractEN{{#1}}}


% Определение титульной страницы.
\def\maketitle{
    \newlength{\ML}
    \settowidth{\ML}{«\underline{\hspace{0.7cm}}» \underline{\hspace{2cm}}}
  \newpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    \@ministry~\@country
    \vspace{0.5cm}
  
    \MakeUppercase{\@fulluniversityname}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \@institute
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \@department~(\@shortdepartment)
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{flushleft}
     УДК: \@UDC
    \end{flushleft}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
  Работа защищена\\
  «\underline{\hspace{0.7cm}}» \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \the\year~г.\\
  Оценка \underline{\hspace{\ML}}\\
  Председатель ГЭК, \@ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommissiondegree\\
  \underline{\hspace{\ML}} \@ChairmanOfTheStateCertificationCommission
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
Допустить к защите\\
«\underline{\hspace{0.7cm}}» \underline{\hspace{2cm}} \the\year~г.\\
Заведующий кафедрой ВТиЭ,\\
\@departmentchiefdegree\\
\underline{\hspace{\ML}} \@departmentchief\\
\end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}%
\vspace{2cm}

    {\MakeUppercase{\@title}}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \textsc{ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ЗАПИСКА К ВЫПУСКНОЙ КВАЛИФИКАЦИОННОЙ РАБОТЕ}
    \vspace{1.0cm}
\end{center}

\bigskip

\begin{center}
\uline{\hfill \@docname.\@groupnumber.\@GradebookNumber~ПЗ \hfill}
\end{center}


\noindent Студент группы: \uline{\hspace{\ML} \@groupnumber \hfill \@author}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\noindent Руководитель работы: \uline{\hspace{1cm} \@supervisordegree \hfill \@supervisor}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\noindent Консультанты: \uline{\hspace{1cm} \@Consultantdegree \hfill \@Consultant}
\vspace{0.5cm}

\noindent Нормоконтролер: \uline{\hspace{1cm} \@NormControllerdegree \hfill \@NormController}
\vspace{0.5cm}
%\hfill
\vfill

\begin{center}
  Барнаул~\@date~г.
\end{center}
  \newpage
  }

% Определение страницы с рефератом.
\def\makeabstract{
  \newpage
  \begin{center}
  РЕФЕРАТ
  \end{center}
  
  Полный объём работы составляет \formbytotal{TotPages}{страниц}{у}{ы}{}, включая
\formbytotal{totalcount@figure}{рисун}{ок}{ка}{ков} и
\formbytotal{totalcount@table}{таблиц}{у}{ы}{}.

    \@abstractRU

    Ключевые слова: \@keysRU.

    Дипломная работа оформлена с помощью системы компьютерной вёрстки \TeX{} и его расширения \XeTeX{} 
из дистрибутива \textit{TeX Live}.

  \begin{center}
  ABSTRACT
  \end{center}
  
  The total amount of work is \formbytotal{TotPages}{page}{}{}{'s}, include
  \formbytotal{totalcount@figure}{image}{}{}{'s} and \formbytotal{totalcount@table}{table}{}{}{'s}.
  
  \@abstractEN
  
  Keyword: \@keysEN.
  
  Thesis is framed using the computer layout system \TeX{} and its extension \XeTeX{}
from the distribution \textit{TeX Live}.
  }

% Определение последней страницы.
\def\makelastpage{
  \newpage
  \begin{center}
  ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ЛИСТ ВКР
  \end{center}
  
  Выпускная квалификационная работа выполнена мной совершенно самостоятельно. Все использованные в работе материалы и концепции из опубликованной научной литературы и других источников имеют ссылки на них.\\
  
  «\underline{\hspace{0.7cm}}» \underline{\hspace{4cm}} \the\year~г.\\
  
  \underline{\hspace{5cm}} \underline{\@author}
  }  
\endinput
```

Build log:

```
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 7.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count529
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 7.
\@outlinefile=\write7


Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

./main.tex:7: Undefined control sequence.
\__hook begindocument ...ame extras\cref@language 
                                                  \endcsname }\@ifundefined ...
l.7 \begin{document}
                    
? 
./main.tex:7: Emergency stop.
\__hook begindocument ...ame extras\cref@language 
                                                  \endcsname }\@ifundefined ...
l.7 \begin{document}
                    
End of file on the terminal!

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 38970 strings out of 477299
 771365 string characters out of 5838338
 1579887 words of memory out of 5000000
 57935 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 404473 words of font info for 63 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 108i,1n,128p,733b,247s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: the error is the undefined `\cref@language `. the hyperref warning is harmless, it should disappear with the next compilation.

Comment: It doesn't disappear, tried few times and I am getting same error

Comment: The error must be naturally be fixed  ask the author of the class.